# Should we give overflow:hidden to those div for which we are not giving height?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser, compatibility

Should we give overflow:hidden to those div for which we are not giving height?

```
#Container {width:900px;margin:0 auto}
```

for `#header` which has other elements inside then should i give `overflow:hidden` to `#header` or i should give fixed height to `#header`.

What is the difference between both?

```
#header {}

#footer {}
```

Comment: Why would we want to do that? Is there some special reasoning or technique behind it?

Comment: because if we dont give overflow:hidden then if we use position relative to any div. it create problem.

Comment: @Pekka: hmm that is good point to ask OP :)

Comment: Mmh... if you don't specify the height, then the container is as heigh as its children, so there is no overflow...

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: if it creates problem, then why ask should we use it?

Comment: @jitendra can you elaborate on what problem this creates? I don't entirely understand yet what you mean.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Is it good to define fixed height even container will take height as its children?

Comment: Aaah, it's a clearfix alternative. I see now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not needed.

That rule is used as a work around to allow a container to take the full height of its child elements when they are floated. So unless you're floating elements inside it, the rule is extraneous, as there will be no overflow because the height is not specified.

See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) for more info on why you would use `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Is it same thing if we give fixed height or we give overflow:hidden?

Comment: I got your point thanks. so if i give position:relative to #header then give position:absolute for inside elements then also we will not need to clear float

Comment: With the exception of using `overflow: hidden` for clearing floats, that rule is used in combination with a fixed height to hide all contents that would appear beyond the fixed height. I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to achieve with `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: but as alternative to overflow: hidden we can give fixed height  also to parent div to expand parent div to inside elements. quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html then what is the difference giving overflow: hidden or fixed height  to parent div?

Comment: Something with a fixed height won't expand - the height is fixed.